# Search List for variable for comparison using contains

Tags: apex, list, string, loop, contains

I am trying to find the Name variable in a list to use the contains() method to search for the Name of the Activity_Assignment__c but am getting an error:

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void Contains(String) from the type List<Activity_Assignment__c> (64:44)

My code is below where I am seeing the issue:

```
        // Build out completed list of assignments -- if there are any
    List<Activity_Assignment__c> currentAssignments = [SELECT Id, Name, Status__c, Actual_Minutes__c, Onboarding_Activity__r.Expected_Duration__c, Employee__c, Employee__r.Name, Onboarding_Activity__c, Onboarding_Activity__r.Name, Onboarding_Activity__r.URL__c, Onboarding_Activity__r.Type__c, Onboarding_Activity__r.Trailhead_Points__c, Onboarding_Activity__r.Onboarding__r.Id, Onboarding_Activity__r.Onboarding__r.Name
    FROM Activity_Assignment__c WHERE Employee__c IN :contacts];

    // Loop completed assignments to set as inactive -- if there are any
    for (Activity_Assignment__c complete : currentAssignments){
        if (complete.IsActive__c = true){
            complete.IsActive__c = false;
        }
            if (!currentAssignments.IsEmpty()){
                update currentAssignments;
            }
    }

    // Build out assignments for each contact
    List<Activity_Assignment__c> assignments = new List<Activity_Assignment__c>();
    for (Contact contact : contacts) {
        if (contact.Onboarding__c != null) {

            // Retrieve the onboarding from the map
            Onboarding__c onboarding = onboardingMap.get(contact.Onboarding__c);

            // Add each assignment to list of new assignments
            for (Onboarding_Activity__c activity : onboarding.Onboarding_Activities__r) {
                if (currentAssignments.Contains(activity.Name))
                assignments.add(
                    new Activity_Assignment__c(
                        Onboarding_Activity__c = activity.Id, 
                        Employee__c = contact.Id));
            }
        }
    }

    // Insert the assignments -- if there are any
    if (!assignments.isEmpty()) {
        insert assignments;
    }
}
```

}

Under the "// Add each assignment to list of new assignments" I am attempting to find the name of the activity assignment in comparison to the new activity.Name and if found, do this, or do that.

Is there a way to do this with the list?

The goal here is to find any of the currentAssignments Name on the Activity_Assignment__c, and if they exist, mark them again as completed when the new list is built out.

Revised code below that worked:

```
// Build out completed list of assignments -- if there are any
    List<Activity_Assignment__c> currentAssignments = [SELECT Id, Name, Status__c, Actual_Minutes__c, Onboarding_Activity__r.Expected_Duration__c, Employee__c, Employee__r.Name, Onboarding_Activity__c, Onboarding_Activity__r.Name, Onboarding_Activity__r.URL__c, Onboarding_Activity__r.Type__c, Onboarding_Activity__r.Trailhead_Points__c, Onboarding_Activity__r.Onboarding__r.Id, Onboarding_Activity__r.Onboarding__r.Name
    FROM Activity_Assignment__c WHERE Employee__c IN :contacts];

    // build out set to track name (common field) for completed assignments
    Set<String> names = new Set<String>();

    // loop to add names to set
    for (Activity_Assignment__c complete : currentAssignments){
        names.add(complete.Onboarding_Activity__r.Name);
    }

    // Loop completed assignments to set as inactive -- if there are any
    for (Activity_Assignment__c complete : currentAssignments){
        if (complete.IsActive__c = true){
            complete.IsActive__c = false;
        }
            if (!currentAssignments.IsEmpty()){
                update currentAssignments;
            }
    }

    // Build out assignments for each contact
    List<Activity_Assignment__c> assignments = new List<Activity_Assignment__c>();
    for (Contact contact : contacts) {
        if (contact.Onboarding__c != null) {

            // Retrieve the onboarding from the map
            Onboarding__c onboarding = onboardingMap.get(contact.Onboarding__c);

            // Add each assignment to list of new assignments
            for (Onboarding_Activity__c activity : onboarding.Onboarding_Activities__r) {
                if (!names.Contains(activity.Name))
                assignments.add(
                    new Activity_Assignment__c(
                        Onboarding_Activity__c = activity.Id, 
                        Employee__c = contact.Id));

                        else if (names.Contains(activity.Name))
                        assignments.add(
                            new Activity_Assignment__c(
                                Onboarding_Activity__c = activity.Id, 
                                Employee__c = contact.Id,
                                Status__c = 'Completed'));

            }
        }
    }

    // Insert the assignments -- if there are any
    if (!assignments.isEmpty()) {
        insert assignments;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a separate Set to track these values:

```
Set<String> names = new Set<String>();
```

...

```
for (Activity_Assignment__c complete : currentAssignments){
  names.add(complete.Name));
```

...

```
 if (names.contains(activity.Name))
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you.